# Node: Receive JSON in a writable stream

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a MongoDB CursorStream and I want to pipe it to a custom WritableStream, that I wrote (TypeScript):

```
class NormalizerStream extends stream.Writable {
    constructor(opts?: stream.WritableOptions) {
        super(opts);
    }
    public _write(data: Buffer, encoding: string, callback: Function): void;
    public _write(data: string, encoding: string, callback: Function): void;
    public _write(data: any, encoding: string, callback: Function): void {
        console.log(data);
        callback();
    }
}
```

I open a connection to my database and retrieve all documents from a collection and I want to pipe it into my NormalizerStream to normalize the data and save the result in another collection.
So I am doing this (JavaScript):

```
Mongo.checkNative(function (db) {
    db.collection('users').find({}).stream().pipe(new NormalizerStream());
});
```

But when running the code, I always get this error:

```
TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
```

Is there some kind of restriction for JSON objects, that I cannot pipe them? Or am I simply doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, that I obviously need to implement a Transformation Stream, not a Writable Stream. I am still not quite sure why a Writable Stream does not take JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem trying to parse knex data from postgres.  After looking through the node source it turns out that you must construct your Writable Stream with objectMode: true and a highWaterMark.  Then your write method will get JSON chunks.  Otherwise you will see the error above.

```
   var writableStream = new stream.Writable(
  {
    objectMode : true,
    highWaterMark : 16,
    write : function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
      console.log("write", chunk);
      callback();
    },
    writev : function(chunk, callback) {
      console.log("writeev", chunk);
      callback();
    }
});
```